# owncloud 10.3.2 SMB shares, only one user can acces at a time

Tags: smb, owncloud, network-share

I have a problem with owncloud 10.3.2. I added SMB shares to owncloud, however, only one user can acces them at any given time. All the other users that try to sign in get the following error when trying to access a folder:

`Some of the configured external mount points are not connected. Please click on the red row(s) for more detail`

Clicking on a red row gives: 
`Couldn't get the information from the Owncloud server:0`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. When I went to my owncloud url and signed in, I got redirected to the same sign-in page, different url. Cookies were saved. Clearing cookies after the first failed log-in fixed it.